# Calculation of a charge in a spherical conducting shell

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, electricity

I have spherical conducting  shell connected grounding.
[image]

the point charge q in the center of the shell, need to calculate what is worth?

teacher said that it need to be q=q' where q' it's charge on the shell?

someone can explain me what happen here?
thank you

Comment: A charge of $-q$ is induced on the inside surface of the spherical conducting shell and there is no change on the outside surface of the conducting shell because it is grounded.

Answer (score 1):

Since no Electric field can be present in the spherical hollow conductor, The net charge should be $0$ (Inside the spherical shell)[Via Gauss Law] This will induce a $-q$ charge at the inner surface of shell.

The Outer surface potential is equal to that of ground. Hence $$ \frac{Q}{4\pi \epsilon_{o}R}=0$$
Thus there is no charge on the outer surface too. Hope it solves your doubt.

Cheers